# Testing react custom hook (react-testing-library)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I need to find a way to test this custom hook.

1. make sure that `element.addEventListener` is being called, with `transitionend` and `callback`
2. emulate `transitionend` event, and make sure that `element.removeEventListener`, with `animationend` and `callback` is being called

```
const useAnimation = ({ draggable, ifWaiting }) => {
   const [ifAnimationAlive, setAnimation] = useState(true);

   const element = draggable.current && draggable.current.resizableElement && draggable.current.resizableElement.current;

   const callback = useCallback(() => {
      setAnimation(false);
      element.removeEventListener('animationend', callback);
   }, [element]);

   useEffect(() => {
      if (element && ifWaiting && ifAnimationAlive) {
         element.addEventListener('transitionend', callback);
      }
   }, [element, ifWaiting, ifAnimationAlive, callback]);

   return ifAnimationAlive;
};
```

I have managed to find a lot of examples with `addEventListener`. But none of them worked for me, because they tested it with the `document`, and I want it to work with a specific element.

So far I've managed to make something like this:

```
 test('should call addEventListener', () => {
      const ifWaiting = true;
      const draggable = {
         current: {
            resizableElement: {
               current: {
                  addEventListener: jest.fn()
               }
            }
         }
      }

      renderHook(() => useAnimation, { initialProps: { draggable, ifWaiting }});

      expect(draggable.current.resizableElement.current.addEventListener).toBeCalled()
   })
```

I have mocked `addEventListener`, and `draggable` element, passing `ifWaiting` as `true`, so that `addEventListener` could be called.

But test says that the function has not been called.

Answer (score 0):

[`renderHook`](https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/reference/api#renderhook) is being used incorrectly in your test, meaning the hook is never called.

Either call the hook with its arguments directly inside the callback function:

```js
renderHook(() => useAnimation({ draggable, ifWaiting }));
```

Or use the hook as the callback and pass its props in the options:

```js
renderHook(useAnimation, { initialProps: { draggable, ifWaiting } });
```